# Slider width issue

Tags: javascript

I have some issues with draggable slider.. I would appriciate if someone would take a peek with new fresh mind because mine has frozen..

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/370/)

I have 2 problems:

- I would like the slider to be 100% of screen width *(don't cofuse slider width with **slide** width)* but something somewhere doesn't add up.. If you try different preview window sizes and hit *Run*, there's always different width of *empty void* after last slide.. What could cause this?
- I would love to have `2px margin` between slides, unfortunately `.width()` doesn't take margin into account.. Any suggestions how to solve that?

---

*Ps!* Slides widths are intentionally fixed sizes and that's what I was going for.

Comment: For your second problem, I would use `.outerWidth( true )`: https://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: @Kocik Thank you, works perfectly!

Comment: Hey for your first question i think it's a problem with your `var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);`.  your max size should be `var max = (sliderwidth-((slides + 1) * slideWidth));`. (where siderWidth is the width of your slider.) From what i see your slider width is alright. It's just scrolling too far left!

Comment: And if you don't want to have the very last gap you should use `.slide { margin-left: 2px; }` and then add pseudo-class `.slide:first-child { margin-left: 0 }` so you don't have a gap in the end and you are save with the gaps for IE8. ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem - you can drag your slider as far as last slide will meet left edge of a window. While the constraint should be right edge of last image meeting right edge of the window.

Changing `max` value to:

```
var max =$('#slider').width()-(slides * slideWidth);
```

Seems to do the trick. Also, updated fiddle for you :)

https://jsfiddle.net/c6fbpzf4/

Solution to the second problem, as mentioned in the comment, is  `.outerWidth( true )` - reference docs here: https://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/